# load file javascript not working in html code

Tags: javascript, html

Here i want to load javascript in html code :

Html file in folder:

`web/index.html`

Javascript file in folder:

`web/assets/script.js`

Html load script code :

`<script type="type/javascript" href="assets/script.js">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't load script with href, try with this code :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/script.js"></script>`